# Connect device (iPad or iPhone) to iMac

Tags: swift, iphone, ipad, usb

How can I detect with Swift whether my device (iPad or iPhone) is connected to an iMac (with the USB-Cable) from source code. So the aim is that I want to start my app and then there is a screen where I can see whether the device is connected or not.

Is this possible?

Comment: SwiftUI is for UI, it doesn't detect anything it doesn't connect to peripherals

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfacefaceIdiom == .pad {
...
}
```

to check whether ipad or iphone is connected..

just call your individual view when device is connected.